# sending datagridview columns from one page to another page

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have got a little bit doubt in sending values from one page to another......

I have two forms say p1 and p2 ....

i have datagridview in p1 with columns cityname,cityid,citynumber ...like that

now i want to use this values in p2(another form)..

I have seacrhed a lot for this but dint find an exact answer .....

i hope i will find an answer in this area ....

i am using winforms application

any idea or sample code would be greatful to me

many thanks in advance..

Comment: You wrote you are developing WinForms application, so I assume you want to access data contained in one form in another form. This depends on how you design your application and there are many of ways to do it i. e. you can create a property in the class of a form you want to share data with and set it from the form that has got the data.

Comment: Where are you getting the data to populate the `DataGridView`?

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is creating a form to hold your data, which then calls other forms.
A base form, the data held here can then be used and altered anywhere in your application.
Alternatively if you do not actually need two forms you could have multiple tabs in one form.
It honestly depends how you are using the data , a little bit more information and perhaps we could help you more.